# FFMPEG : How to transcode Attached Picture (APIC) from source mp3 file to destination mp3 file using FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, id3v2

I have input file as 02.mp3. I want to change it to mp3 file with some bit rate. While doing so, I want to preserve all the metadata plus the APIC, attached picture corresponding to image should also be transfered to the destionation file. I am using FFMPEG and i am using the following command...

ffmpeg -y -i 02.mp3 -id3v2_version 3 -ab 128000 -ss 0 -acodec libmp3lame -f mp3 -ac 2 -ar 44100 output.mp3

source file: 02.mp3
destination file : output.mp3.

But in destination file, i am not getting APIC(attached picture corresponding to 02.mp3).I am getting all other mp3 tags in output.mp3 except for APIC. How to get APIC in destinaton file as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to patch your FFMPEG source to support support binary in metadata and rebuild. The patch is here:

http://lists.mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2011-December/118085.html

Comment: In fact I would love to if you could share us the built FFMPEG release with the patch given above. I don't have any resources to build the project. Thanking you in advance.